# clear an array before populate with useState in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

How to clear an array and immediately populate with react using hooks (useState)

```
const [log, setLog] = useState([]);

const onSubmit = data => {
  let num = parseInt(data.num);
  setLog([]);
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    axios
      .get(data.url)
      .then(function(response) {
        setLog([...log, { type: "ok", message: "Good" }]);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        setLog([...log, { type: "error", message: "Bad" }]);
      });
  }
};
```

In this code, `setLog([])` fails to clean the array because is asynchronous. How can I handle this? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I am creating a request log to a URL and save the request result. It can be 1 attempt or many attempts and I must record all the responses. Each time I press the submit button, the log must be cleaned and the requests started again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unpopular opinion:

**Use class component. It provides accessor to the current state.**

```
class SomeComponent extends Component {
  state = {
    isSubmitting: false,
    logs: []
  }

  async submit(data){
    const num = data.num;
    if (this.isSubmitting) {
      return;
    }

    let logs = [];
    this.setState({ logs, isSubmitting: true });

    for (const i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      await axios.get(data.url)
        .then(() => {
          logs = logs.concat({ type: "ok", message: "Good" });
          this.setState({ logs });
        })
        .catch(() => {
          logs = logs.concat({ type: "error", message: "Bad" })
          this.setState({ logs })
        })
    }

    this.setState({ isSubmitting: false });
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <form onSubmit={() => this.submit(getSomeData())}></form>
    )
  }
}
```

```
// use this if you want the request to be executed parallely

  async submit(data){
    const num = data.num;
    if (this.isSubmitting) {
      return;
    }

    let logs = [];
    this.setState({ logs, isSubmitting: true });

    const requests = []
    for (const i = 0; i < num; i++) {
      requests.push(
        axios.get(data.url)
          .then(() => {
            logs = logs.concat({ type: "ok", message: "Good" });
            this.setState({ logs });
          })
          .catch(() => {
            logs = logs.concat({ type: "error", message: "Bad" })
            this.setState({ logs })
          })
      )
    }

    await Promise.all(requests)

    this.setState({ isSubmitting: false });
  }
```

Comment: Any approach with useState?

Comment: @Victor you have to put your whole model into one state. For example
```
```

Comment: Look at the answer by @rMonteiro https://stackoverflow.com/a/60489656/5381781

Answer (score 1):

why do you want to do `setLog([])` and then `setLog([...log, ]);` ?

If you want to `setLog` without previous `log` content just do:

```
const [log, setLog] = useState([]);

const onSubmit = data => {
  let num = parseInt(data.num);
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    axios
      .get(data.url)
      .then(function(response) {
        setLog([{ type: "ok", message: "Good" }]);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        setLog([{ type: "error", message: "Bad" }]);
      });
  }
};
```

**edit:** Ok I think I understood what you need. I am not sure but try the following

```
const [log, setLog] = useState([]);

const onSubmit = data => {
  let num = parseInt(data.num);
  setLog([]);
  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    axios
      .get(data.url)
      .then(function(response) {
        setState(prevLog => {
          prevLog.push({ type: "ok", message: "Good" });
          return {prevLog};
        });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        setState(prevLog => {
          prevLog.push({ type: "error", message: "Bad" });
          return {prevLog};
        });
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: no, because is not one request only, there can be many and I must save all the responses.

Comment: @toledorobia ok I think I understood what you need, I edited the answer please try the new code

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work:

```
const [log, setLog] = useState([]);

const onSubmit = data => {
  let num = parseInt(data.num);

  for (let i = 1; i <= num; i++) {
    axios
      .get(data.url)
      .then(function(response) {
        setLog([{ type: "ok", message: "Good" }]);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        setLog([{ type: "error", message: "Bad" }]);
      });
  }
};
```

Comment: no, because is not one request only, there can be many and I must save all the responses and clear the log on every submit